# 3D population density map

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, qgis2threejs

I'd like to make a 3D population density map about a country.

I've got all of the population data of the towns and villages etc. and I've got shp about these areas.

I'd like to make a map like [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/MapPorn/comments/aou0dj/a_cool_way_of_looking_at_population_density/):

[image]

I tried to do this with QGIS ThreeJS plugin. [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rcyvR.jpg) is the result:

[image]

I'd like to add state vector layer above the 3D layer. Is this possible with that plugin?

Can somebody tell me what tool could I use to do this?

Comment: It looks like your output is roughly similar to the first map. Can you please describe what you think is wrong with your map, that you're trying to fix?

Comment: I'd like to add state vector layer above the 3D layer. Is this possible with that plugin?

Comment: I have no idea, but I edited your question so it actually contains your real question. Now there's a chance someone who knows the answer will be able to help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is possible to add a vector layer. You need to load both and select them at the in the plugin menu.

[image]