# 3D map in ThreeJS remove perforation

Tags: qgis, three-js

I did this 3D map with ThreeJS in QGIS:[3D population density map](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/327452/3d-population-density-map)

I almost done, but I need help to remove or fill perforations/hole.

Can anyone help me to do this?

[image]